# How can I list when was all my installed FreeBSD ports built?

Tags: freebsd

I have a FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE system which I now upgrading to 9.0-RELEASE. In this process I need to rebuild all my ports installed.
How can I list the date of last build for each installed port, to be sure, everything was rebuilt now.
I used `portmaster -af` to rebuild everything, but when some build error happens, I continue with the command it gives in the end (with names of the folloing packages in its argument), but I would like to be sure that everything was rebuilt now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls -Alt /var/db/pkg | grep '/$' | tail -n 20` should show 20 oldest apps installed from ports.

Also, `pkg_version -vIL=` command could be usefult to compare versions of installed ports and ports in updated tree.

Comment: 1. the `ls -Alt /var/db/pkg | grep '/$' | tail -n 20` gives me empty result, because `grep '/$'` matches zero lines. I greatly appreciate your answer. So if I mean well the folder dates in `/var/db/pkg` means the build dates of each package?

Comment: Yes, contents of those directories displays actions associated with any of installed port and lists of its files. So, if some of ports was changed or updated, last access time of appropriate directory will be changed too. By the way, you can remove `| grep '/$'` from command (I used it to filter only dirs in `ls` output).